# Error checking duplicate user-input array values

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

I am self-learning Java and am stuck on a simple project. I'd like to receive 6 **unique** 'lottery' numbers from a user.

1. User will be asked to input an integer.
2. Each user input will be placed into an array.
3. If the user inputs a previously input number, I want to prompt to reenter the number again.
4. Recheck the new input. If unique, continue the for loop. If non-unique, run step 3 again.

So far, all I have is:

```
public static int[] userLottoInput()
{
    int[] userNums = new int[6];        
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < userNums.length; i++ ) {
        System.out.printf("Enter Lottery number %d: ", i + 1);
        userNums[i] = keyboard.nextInt();

        for (int k=i; k<userNums.length; k++)  {
            while (k!=i && userNums[k] == userNums[i])  {
                System.out.printf("if");
                System.out.printf("Error! Try again: ");
                userNums[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: I would change the structure of your logic so that you only ever ask the user for input in a single place...

Comment: It's kinda hard to ask what you're asking. SO isn't a place for us to do your code. Do you have a specific problem you need help with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try and keep you logic simple.

- While the user hasn't enter 6 numbers, loop
- Ask the user for a value
- Check to see if it's a duplicate
- If it is, ask the user to re-enter the value
- If it's not (a duplicate) increment the counter to the next element...

For example...

```
public static int[] userLottoInput() {
    int[] userNums = new int[6];
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int i = 0;
    // Keep looping until we fill the array, but
    // allow the control to fall somewhere else
    while (i < userNums.length) {

        System.out.printf("Enter Lottery number %d: ", i + 1);
        userNums[i] = keyboard.nextInt();

        // Check for duplicates
        boolean duplicate = false;
        // We only need to check up to i - 1, as all the
        // other values are defaulted to 0
        // We also don't need to check for the last number entered ;)
        for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
            // Check for duplicated
            if (userNums[k] == userNums[i]) {
                System.out.println("No duplicates allowed, please try again");
                duplicate = true;
                // Break out of the loop as we don't need to check any more..
                break;
            }
        }

        // If no duplicates where found, update i to the next position
        if (!duplicate) {
            i++;
        }            
    }
    return userNums;
}
```

With this, there is only one point at which you prompt the user.  Everything else is used to control the element position (`i`) to meet your requirements.

Now, I'm sure that there are other ways to do this and this is just a simple example ;)

Answer (score 0):

Move the asking of number outside loop, when received the number loop over the numbers array to find a match. If match found re-ask for number (outside the for loop used for finding the match), else if match not found, then add the number to array.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think your for loop is little complicated. Anyways, you can try this :

```
for (int k=0; k<i-1; k++)  {    //Start k=0 means from the first stored value
        while (k!=i && userNums[k] == userNums[i])  {
            System.out.printf("if");
            System.out.printf("Error! Try again: ");
            userNums[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, no doubt in that. 1 iteration will be saved.